# SYMLINK in udev rule

Tags: udev, symbolic-link

I created a udev rule named "/etc/udev/rules.d/75-myusb.rules".

The only thing inside it is this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYMLINK+="myusb"
```

After creating it I plugged a USB drive and a file named myusb is indeed created inside /dev

[image]

Since it is a SYMLINK I did assume that I can use it to navigate into the USB. But it doesn't work that way.

[image]

Am I misunderstanding what a SYMLINK can do or am I missing something here?

Comment: You've created a symbolic link to the block device file on which the USB's filesystem lives; you will still need to *mount* that device somewhere before you can access it: see [Why do we need to mount on Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178077/why-do-we-need-to-mount-on-linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your symlink points to the [device file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) associated with the USB drive. That's different from the [mount point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29) where you can access the file system on your USB drive.

As a device file is not a directory you can't use `cd` with a device file or a symlink pointing to a device file.