# Symbolic links breaking after restart 16.04. LTS (linux)

Tags: 16.04

i created a symbolic link with the below command (on UBUNTU 16.04 LTS 64 bit)

ln -s ttyACM0 ttyS5

to use with a usb pin pad ,but every time i restart the machine the link is broken.

i have little knowledge on linux.After the reboot this command shows that he link already exist.

ln -s ttyACM0 ttyS5 so i have to remove and create again but machine keeps losing the settings.

Please help

Comment: Where do you create that symlink ?

Comment: “/dev” directory

Comment: You probably need to [Create a symlink in /dev using /etc/udev/rules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783357/create-a-symlink-in-dev-using-etc-udev-rules)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `df -h` in a terminal you will see that /dev is "mounted on" udev, not /dev/sdx or anything else indicating a physical disk. udev is a virtual file-system (in memory) that is regenerated every time the system is booted.

That's why your symbolic link disappears on reboot.

Comment: yes i have seen as per above..

is there a way to get around this ,i would really appreciate

Comment: Follow the link @steeldriver provided ..