# Persistant Symbolic Link -Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, udev, symbolic-link

Could somebody assist me in creating a persistent symlink for the block  devices, using udev ?

I have a cloud server, where I can attach a separate device (/dev/xvdb) as a storage.

I want to create a persistent symlink (/dev/test_link) which should always target to /dev/xvdb storage.

Regards,

Comment: Are you just looking to have the device mounted in the same place every time you connect it to your system?  Maybe try giving the USB device a permanent mount point on the system.  USB Drives can change their designation between reboots on the system.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/940060/231142

Comment: yes, but I would like to achieve it using udev and its just for a one-time testing so that I can understand how symlink works persistently using udev rules.

Comment: Ah, OK.  This might help:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/783357/create-a-symlink-in-dev-using-etc-udev-rules

Comment: nope, it didn't help.
I used the given post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/783357/create-a-symlink-in-dev-using-etc-udev-rules  and https://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/#comments
created a rule file with the below settings and still unable to find that symlink created. 
file: /etc/udev/rules.d/81-drive.rules which has below attributes
KERNEL=="xvdb1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{size}=="4192256", SYMLINK+="/dev/prod_data"

Comment: The examples in the posts are of the usb devices, however I am using a virtual block device which is /dev/xvdb1.. would this change something?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev udev runs with the Linux Kernel.  Hardware is controlled by the Linux Kernel, but virtual drives would be controlled by drivers.  So, I don't think that it would be possible for udev to detect if the virtual drive existed or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87101/discussion-between-imrank-and-terrance).